# How do I receive response from a callback url on MAUI app?

Tags: android, cross-platform, openid-connect, maui

I am working on dev of a MAUI app. I call one api endpoint (https://myfirstendpoint) which contains a callback url (https://myappname) in querystring parameters. Now ideally when this first endpoint is hit then a callback should happen on the app and I should receive a code passed in that callback url.

What I have tried:

1. Ensured the endpoints are working as expected in postman
2. Added intent in the AndroidManifest.xml for receiving the callback
3. Added a class with activity name in Android folder (it keeps giving errors)

If someone has worked on it then please guide me with correct procedure/solution for achieving this.

Please be considerate as I am working on MAUI for the first time I might miss out on some of the termionologies while explaining my query.

Comment: Callback urls are usually used when control needs to be returned to your app from an external browser session.  If you are calling an API using HttpClient I’m not sure how that would work

Comment: Thanks @Jason, but what should be the solution for it? Can you suggest some other approach? Basically we are trying to implement login for our specific feature on our app which is based on calling several other apis.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the API you’re using it’s impossible to say

Comment: You can check this document about [Consume a REST-based web service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/rest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response guys. I finally had to change my approach as this never worked and it was an urgent deliverable.

I used [Web Authenticator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=windows) for making it work and it worked then. Posting the answer here for someone who gets stuck like me and wants a solution.